# AttributeError: type object 'Product' has no attribute 'objects'

Tags: python, django

```
Python 3.8.3
asgiref             3.3.1
Django              2.2
django-crispy-forms 1.10.0
djangorestframework 3.11.1
Pillow              7.2.0
pip                 19.2.3
psycopg2            2.8.6
pytz                2020.1
setuptools          41.2.0
sqlparse            0.3.1
```

Sorry, I'm not sure where there is an abnormality in a situation, can you mention me?
Then I posted error information in stackoverflow and presented it with my code, the link is [AttributeError: type object 'Product' has no attribute 'objects'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66310704/attributeerror-type-object-product-has-no-attribute-objects)
, You can click the link to enter and watch...Thank you.

Everyone, help me think about the screen. After I clicked on the product I need add to car, an error appeared, and the product could not be added to my shopping cart. May I ask if this message appears.
File "C:\Users\georgiawang\PycharmProjects\libshopapp\store\views.py", line 195, in updateItem**
product = Product.objects.get(id=productId)
AttributeError: type object'Product' has no attribute'objects'**
Is it because views.py is damaged?

Because **"POST /store/update_item/ HTTP/1.1" 500 59** the information came out a bit unexpectedly, after all, I didn’t mess with the program. I don’t know which side of the program affects QWQ.

Hope to mention me a bit, thank you very much.

遇到問題是:The problems encountered are:

```
product = Product.objects.get(id=productId)
AttributeError: type object 'Product' has no attribute 'objects'


Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
February 22, 2021 - 13:09:19
Django version 2.2, using settings 'libshopapp.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
[22/Feb/2021 13:09:22] "GET /store/ HTTP/1.1" 200 32153
Action: add
Product: 135


1.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "D:\python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "D:\python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\georgiawang\PycharmProjects\libshopapp\store\views.py", line 195, in updateItem**
    product = Product.objects.get(id=productId)
    AttributeError: type object 'Product' has no attribute 'objects'**

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "D:\python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\utils\deprecation.py", line 94, in __call__
    response = response or self.get_response(request)
  File "D:\python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 36, in inner
    response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
  File "D:\python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 90, in response_for_exception
    response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())

2.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\python\Python38\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 137, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  File "D:\python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\handlers.py", line 65, in __call__
    return self.application(environ, start_response)
  File "D:\python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\wsgi.py", line 141, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "D:\python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 75, in get_response
    response = self._middleware_chain(request)
  File "D:\python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 36, in inner
    response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
  File "D:\python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 90, in response_for_exception
    response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
  File "D:\python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 125, in handle_uncaught_exception
    return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)
  File "D:\python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\views\debug.py", line 94, in technical_500_response
    html = reporter.get_traceback_html()
  File "D:\python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\views\debug.py", line 332, in get_traceback_html
    t = DEBUG_ENGINE.from_string(fh.read())
UnicodeDecodeError: 'cp950' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 9735: illegal multibyte sequence

**[22/Feb/2021 13:09:27] "POST /store/update_item/ HTTP/1.1" 500 59**
```

請幫忙看看，謝謝?
please help to see, thank you.

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////code//////////////////////////////////////////////

***/// store / models.py ///***

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse

from django.utils import timezone

class Product(models.Model):
    name     = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    content  = models.TextField(default='')
    price    = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)
    digital  = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=True, blank=True)
    draft    = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    image    = models.ImageField(
        upload_to=imgs,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        width_field="width_field",
        height_field="height_field",
    )
    height_field = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    width_field  = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    updated      = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    timestamp    = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    products = ProductManage()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    @property
    def imageURL(self):
        try:
            url = self.image.url
        except:
            url = ''
        return url

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('store:detail', kwargs={'id': self.id})

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["-timestamp", "-updated"]
```

***/// home / urls.py ///***

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'home'

urlpatterns = [
    # path('order/', views.order, name='order'),
    path('social/', views.socialview, name='social'),
    path('about/', views.aboutview, name='about'),
    path('contact/', views.contact, name='contact'),
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

***/// store / urls.py ///***

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'store'

urlpatterns = [
    # Leave as empty string for base url
    path('', views.store, name='store'),
    path('cart/', views.cart, name='cart'),

    path('create/', views.productCreate, name='create'),
    path('<int:id>/', views.productDetail, name='detail'),
    path('<int:id>/update/', views.productUpdate, name='update'),
    path('<int:id>/delete/', views.productDelete, name='delete'),

    path('checkout/', views.checkout, name='checkout'),

    path('update_item/', views.updateItem, name='update_item'),
    # path('update_item/', views.updateItem, name='update_item'),
    path('process_order/', views.processOrder, name='process_order'),

    path('searchbar/', views.searchbar, name='searchbar'),
]
```

***/// store / views.py ///***

```
import datetime
import json

from django.contrib import messages
from django.core.paginator import Paginator, PageNotAnInteger, EmptyPage
from django.http import JsonResponse, HttpResponseRedirect, Http404
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect

from .forms import ProductForms
from .models import Product
from .utils import cartData, guestOrder

from django.utils import timezone

def updateItem(request):
    data = json.loads(request.body)
    productId = data['productId']
    action = data['action']
    print('Action:', action)
    print('Product:', productId)

    customer = request.user.customer
    product = Product.objects.get(id=productId)
    order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(customer=customer, complete=False)

    orderItem, created = OrderItem.objects.get_or_create(order=order, product=product)

    if action == 'add':
        orderItem.quantity = (orderItem.quantity + 1)
    elif action == 'remove':
        orderItem.quantity = (orderItem.quantity - 1)

    orderItem.save()

    if orderItem.quantity <= 0:
        orderItem.delete()

    return JsonResponse('Item was added', safe=False)
```

***/// cart.js ///***

question:  "POST /store/update_item/ HTTP/1.1" 500 59

```
var updateBtns = document.getElementsByClassName('update-cart')

for (i = 0; i < updateBtns.length; i++) {
    updateBtns[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
        var productId = this.dataset.product
        var action = this.dataset.action
        console.log('productId:', productId, 'Action:', action)
        console.log('USER:', user)

        if (user == 'AnonymousUser'){
            addCookieItem(productId, action)
        }else{
            updateUserOrder(productId, action)
        }
    })
}

function updateUserOrder(productId, action){
    console.log('User is authenticated, sending data...')

        var url = '/store/update_item/'

        fetch(url, {
            method:'POST',
            headers:{
                'Content-Type':'application/json',
                'X-CSRFToken':csrftoken,
            },
            body:JSON.stringify({'productId':productId, 'action':action})
        })
        .then((response) => {
           return response.json();
        })
        .then((data) => {
            location.reload()
        });
}

function addCookieItem(productId, action){
    console.log('User is not authenticated')

    if (action == 'add'){
        if (cart[productId] == undefined){
        cart[productId] = {'quantity':1}

        }else{
            cart[productId]['quantity'] += 1
        }
    }

    if (action == 'remove'){
        cart[productId]['quantity'] -= 1

        if (cart[productId]['quantity'] <= 0){
            console.log('Item should be deleted')
            delete cart[productId];
        }
    }
    console.log('CART:', cart)
    document.cookie ='cart=' + JSON.stringify(cart) + ";domain=;path=/"

    location.reload()
}
```

***/// froms.py ///***

```
from django import forms
from store.models import Product, RegistrationData

class ProductForms(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = [
            'name',
            'price',
            'digital',
            'image',
            'width_field',
            'height_field',
            'content',
        ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

where you import your models.py in your views.py?
just import your models file in your views and then you will be able to access your models classes in your views file.
something just like this:

```
from <models_directory> import models 
def updateItem(request):
    data = json.loads(request.body)
    productId = data['productId']
    product = models.Product.objects.get(id=productId)
    # and other...
```

Comment: Sorry, I have modified it. Please take a look at what my views.py import contains.
Here are all views.py content  --->   https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/5kHWgk7W7W/, please check.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you did not define class name or function or varible with same name

Answer (score 0):

well i recently had that same problem, in class Meta of my model i set abstract = True.
Make sure you did not do the same and make sure a view name or task name is not the same as your Model name